# Python: Removing elements from list by index based on elements in another list

Tags: python, list

So I have a list

```
a_list = [0,3,4,7,9,11,15]
```

and a list of outliers

```
outliers = [0,3,4]
```

The outliers is the list of indexes that need to be removed from a_list

So in this case, remove the elements in index 0, 3, 4 from a_list. Result should be:

```
remove these = [0,7,9]
a_list = [0,3,4,11,15]
```

If I use the del method, the index will change so once I remove 0th index, I will still remove the 3rd index but instead remove 9 and 4th index will remove 15.

How can I remove items from a_list with the indexes specified in a separate list?

Comment: Remove the indices in reverse order?

Comment: Start from the largest one, i.e. remove 4th element first, then 3rd, then 0th.

Comment: first, get all the values in a different list and then remove it

Comment: Do something like `new list = [j for i, j in enumerate(a_list) if i not in [0, 7, 9]]` .... another solution is instead of removing items, replace them with a temporary number or character eg 0... and then add an extra line... `list(filter((0).__ne__, a_list))` or `list(filter(lambda a: a != 2, a_list))`

Answer (score 2):

Compare index to `outliers` list. If the `index` is matching to `outliers` then skip it.

```
print([x for i, x in enumerate(a_list) if i not in outliers])
```

Better to use `set(outliers)` if outliers contain the duplicate elements.

Comment: A possible optimization is to convert `outliers` to a `set`

Comment: Could be better to use a set but I assumed outliers contains distinct element

Answer (score -1):

Here is a real quick implementation based on what the others were commenting about.

```
a_list = [0,3,4,7,9,11,15]
outliers = [0,3,4]
outliers.reverse()
for i in outliers:
    del a_list[i]
print(a_list)
```

Simply call `outliers.reverse()` before iterating and delete as normal.